# MassTransit handling Faults in Saga

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, masstransit, saga

I'm trying to handle specific `Fault` inside Saga instance like described in https://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/exceptions.html#faults. 
In my`StateMachine` class I have:

```cs
Event(
    () => OnError,
    x => x
        .CorrelateById(context => context.Message.Message.CorrelationId))

DuringAny(WhenError());

...

public Event<CustomCommand> CustomCommandReceived { get; protected set; }

public Event<Fault<CustomCommand>> OnError { get; protected set; }

...

private EventActivityBinder<RequestSaga, Fault<CustomCommand>> WhenError()
{
    return When(OnError)
        .Then(context =>
        {
            context.Instance.Status = RequestProcessingStatus.Error;
        });
}
```

But when `Fault<CustomCommand>` occured, code inside handler did'not execute and `Fault<CustomCommand>` message goes to `..._skipped` queue.

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

Is `CustomCommands` handled in the *Initial* state, and throwing the exception? That would prevent the saga instance from being saved, and thus after the fault is published, would cause the fault to be ignored since `DuringAny` does not include the *Initial* or *Final* states. If you want to handle the fault in the *Initial* state, you need to add it explicitly.

```
Initially(WhenError());
DuringAny(WhenError());
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! That was not my problem, I handle faulds in custom saga state. But it's greate to know `DuringAny` does not meen `Initially`.

My problem was in Saga misconfiguration - one of consumers was wrongly pointed to Saga queue and handle messages of type he does not know.